# how to fix/redesign template recursive dependency

Tags: c++, templates

I have a `Process` class and want to pair it with one of the `Implementation`s using templates.

**Process**:

```
template <typename ImplementationType>
class Process
{
public:
    Process() :   pid(0), _impl(*this) { }            

    int execute() { _impl.execute(); }
    int getPid() { return pid; }

private:
    ImplementationType _impl;

    // process specific details
    int pid;
};
```

**SimpleProcessImplementation**:

```
template <typename ImplementationType>
class SimpleProcessImplementation
{
public:
    SimpleProcessImplementation(Process<ImplementationType>& process) : _process(process) { }

    int execute() { std::cout << "Simple implementation of Process " << _process.getPid() << "\n"; }

private:
    Process<ImplementationType>& _process;
};
```

And I intend to use it as:

```
Process<SimpleProcessImplementation> p;    // Line 50
p.execute();
```

As seen from the example, there is clearly a recursive dependency on `SimpleProcessImplementation` which fails the compilation of the program.

```
template.cpp:50:40: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<class ImplementationType> class Process’
template.cpp:50:40: error:   expected a type, got ‘SimpleProcessImplementation’
template.cpp:50:43: error: invalid type in declaration before ‘;’ token
template.cpp:51:7: error: request for member ‘execute’ in ‘p’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
```

Is it possible at all to implement this using templates? or Inheritance of `Implementation` class hierarchy is the only way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SimpleProcessImplementation` is not a class (it's a class template), so it does not fit into `Process`'s template argument slot, and the compiler complains about that. I think you meant

```
class SimpleProcessImplementation
{
public:
    SimpleProcessImplementation(Process<SimpleProcessImplementation>& process) : _process(process) { }

    int execute() { std::cout << "Simple execution of Process " << _process.getPid() << "\n"; }

private:
    Process<SimpleProcessImplementation>& _process;
};
```

Comment: Yup, missed it! Thanks :-)